# Como evitar división de componentes en el salto de pagina al exportar PDF con ‘jspdf’ y ‘html2canvas’

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

Estoy intentando exportar mi panel de gestión con "jspdf" y "html2canvas" en mi componente principal le pongo de clase "panelGestion" para poder exportarlo al pdf, que sucede que al crear el pdf los componentes se cortan a mitad cambio de pagina en el pdf.

Como podría conseguir que los componentes no se corten por la mitad al cambiar de pagina al crear un pdf nuevo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
const exportarGraficasPdf = async () => {
    // Selecciona el componente que quieres exportar
    const componente = document.querySelector('.panelGestion');

    // Captura una imagen del componente
    const canvas = await html2canvas(componente);

    // Convierte la imagen en datos de imagen
    const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    // Crea un nuevo documento PDF en orientación horizontal
    const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');  // A4 size page of PDF in landscape orientation

    // Calcula el ancho y el alto de la imagen manteniendo la relación de aspecto original
    const imgWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth() - 20;  // leave 10mm margin at each side
    const imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;

    // Calcula el número de páginas necesarias
    const pages = Math.ceil(imgHeight / (pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight() - 20));  // leave 10mm margin at the bottom

    for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        // Añade una nueva página si no es la primera
        if (i !== 0) {
            pdf.addPage();
        }

        // Calcula la posición de inicio de la imagen
        const startY = i * (pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight());

        // Añade la imagen al documento PDF
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, -startY, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    }

    // Guarda el documento PDF
    pdf.save("informe.pdf");
};
```